# Row operation in R to populate column based on prior row and other variables?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

| Index | A | B | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | NA |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | NA |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | NA |

I want to replace the NA's in 'Y' based on a function of A, B, and the prior value of Y such that Y = Prior Y + A - B

Therefore the final result should be:

| Index | A | B | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 |

This seems like a simple problem, but between all of the various functions out there (apply, reduce, accumulate, lag, etc) I'm not sure what the best approach is. Hoping for a solution with dplyr. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()` on the combined vector `c(Y[1], (A - B)[-1])`:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  mutate(Y = cumsum(c(Y[1], (A - B)[-1])))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  Index     A     B     Y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     1     1
2     2     2     1     2
3     3     2     1     3
4     4     2     1     4
```

Comment: Confirming this works - after I posted this question I pinged a friend and he also suggested I try cumsum, but your code is a lot more elegant than what I implemented.

In my actual problem, the "Y[1]" is actually the last row (last defined as max date) for a group, but I can look that value up separately.